# Spotfire row color based on column value

Tags: colors, formatting, row, conditional-statements, spotfire

[image: Color row based on Wellname]

I can only figure out how to color 1 column - I'm trying to color the whole row based on the Wellname.

Answer (score 2):

You can color **alternate rows** by adding a rule in **Properties --> colors**

1. Click **Add Rule**
2. select **Rule Type = Boolean Expression** 
2. Value = **Mod(RowId(),2)=0**

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately Spotfire doesn't support row-based coloring.

if you're creating an analysis with multiple visualizations, you could potentially use a details visualization to limit the rows displayed in the table to a selected well.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer I found on Tibco Community:
You can put your expression instead of the one from an example.

[image: From Tibco Community]